# How to attach a process to the current debugger programmatically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, automation, attach-to-process

I have 2 projects in the solution that compile to *A.exe* and *B.exe*
*A* will start *B* and connect to it through a named pipe. I want to test the connection between them so I'd like to [attach to both at the same time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022). Doing that manually every time is very tedious and inconvenient, especially when B will close after a timeout if it doesn't receive any data from A. Therefore I tried this

```
if (IsDebuggerPresent())
    DebugActiveProcess(processId);
```

However it seems **B is attached to A's debugger instead of Visual Studio's**. So how can I attach B to VS debugger ***automatically***?

I have windbg at hand for debugging crash dumps so it may also be a solution, as long as it can be done *without multiple user interactions*

Answer (score 0):

**Attach to a process `B` programatically**

***Method 1: Using VS***

1. Open `B.vcxproj` and not your solution (`.sln` containning projects `A` and `B`)
2. Put your breakpoints

[image]

3. Run this dos command from your project **A** via `system()` (or other variant):

   devenv /nosplash /run "G:\Logiciels\B\B.vcxproj" /nosplash /debugexe
4. `devenv` is a command in your VS path. In my case it in:

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC
5. When you run this command, B project is opened and break point reached.

***Method 2: Using Windbg***

Just call this command:

```
windbg -p ProcessID
```

**Attach to a process `B` graphically**

Open your B project in another instance, and attach to it like this :

[image]

And select your B.exe:

[image]

Comment: I think you missed the "programatically". This is how you do it manually.

Comment: @MSalters Ah ok, i don't see this remarque. Thanks.